# What kind of a Youtube API Feed is this?

Tags: youtube-api

So I have this broken Youtube playlist (PHP loop that gets playlist info from Youtube feed). Oddly, it broke when a few duplicate/failed upload videos were deleted, no clue why.

Anyways, I have this playlist feed URL which doesn't seem to work, but was working earlier: http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/6549D4CA7BB99B16?v=2

What is the number following /playlists/? It doesn't look like a playlist ID (since they appear to start with 'PL') or a user ID http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PL6549D4CA7BB99B16.

I have several such feeds in the code, they all used to work. Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the playlist ID -- YouTube apparently just recently instituted a change that requires appending the 'PL' characters, like this:

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/playlists/PL6549D4CA7BB99B16?v=2

Comment: Thanks so much for mentioning that! I was going nuts trying to debug this script and then I noticed the feed URL wasn't responding.

Comment: Looks like it wasn't an intentional change ... see https://code.google.com/p/gdata-issues/issues/detail?id=3599 (this was also addressed in another Stack Overflow question). That bug report says the issue is fixed, now, so the original URL (without the leading 'PL') should now be working.

Comment: I see, thanks for elaborating. I was trying to fix a media player that someone else had created and was scratching my head quite a bit, never having worked with the Youtube API before.